# Cannot find module './modules/shipper/shipper.module' in angular9?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have an angular app in which i am doing lazy loading. My folder structure is like this

```
app
 modules
   shipper
     addshipper
     shipper
     shipper.module.ts
     shipper.routing.module.ts
   transporter
app.routing.module.ts
app.module.ts
```

in my `app-routing.module.ts` i have `lazyload` my `shipper` `module` like this

```
{ path: 'addshipper', loadChildren : './modules/shipper/shipper.module#ShipperModule'}
```

in my `shipper.module.ts` i have following

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AddshipperComponent } from './addshipper/addshipper.component';
import { ShipperRoutingModule } from './shipper-routing.module';

export const options: Partial<IConfig> | (() => Partial<IConfig>) = null;
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AddshipperComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ShipperRoutingModule
    ],
    providers: []
})
export class ShipperModule { }
```

Inside of my `shipper.module.ts` i have following `child` `routes`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from '@app/authguard.guard';
import { AddshipperComponent } from './addshipper/addshipper.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
      path: '',
      children: [
        { path: '', component: AddshipperComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard] } 
      ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ShipperRoutingModule { }
```

and in the `side nave` of my app i have the link like this

```
<a  routerLink="/addshipper" class="nav-link">
   <i class="fa fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
   <p>Add Shipper</p>
</a>
```

But the problem is that when i click on the `Add Shipper` link so i am getting this `error` in `console`

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './modules/shipper/shipper.module'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to import **CommonModule** within your shipper.module.ts

```
imports: [CommonModule,
 BrowserModule, ShipperRoutingModule ],
```

and you need to export your public components

```
exports:[AddshipperComponent]
```